# What exactly are iblog files in mysql

Tags: mysql, innodb, logs

I would like to understand these ibdata files as these play vital role in the crash recovery procedure. I could not find proper resources over the web for this.

Answer (score 21):

## ibdata1

The file `ibdata1` is the system tablespace for the InnoDB infrastructure.

It contains several classes for information vital for InnoDB

- Table Data Pages
- Table Index Pages
- Data Dictionary
- MVCC Control Data
- Undo Space
- Rollback Segments
- Double Write Buffer (Pages Written in the Background to avoid OS caching)
- Insert Buffer (Changes to Secondary Indexes)

[**Click Here to see a Pictorial Representation**](http://www.scribd.com/doc/31337494/XtraDB-InnoDB-internals-in-drawing)

You can divorce Data and Index Pages from ibdata1 by enabling [innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table). This will cause any newly created InnoDB table to store data and index pages in an external `.ibd` file.

Example

- [datadir](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_datadir) is `/var/lib/mysql`
- `CREATE TABLE mydb.mytable (...) ENGINE=InnoDB;`, creates `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.frm`
- `innodb_file_per_table` enabled, Data/Index Pages Stored in `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.ibd`
- `innodb_file_per_table` disabled, Data/Index Pages Stored in `ibdata1`

No matter where the InnoDB table is stored, InnoDB's functionality requires looking for table metadata and storing and retrieving [**MVCC**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) info to support [**ACID compliance**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) and [**Transaction Isolation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_isolation).

Here are my past articles on separating table data and indexes from ibdata1

- `Oct 29, 2010` : [**My Original Post in StackOverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261)
- `Nov 26, 2011` : [ERROR 1114 (HY000) at line 6308 in file & The table user_analysis is full](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8411/error-1114-hy000-at-line-6308-in-file-the-table-user-analysis-is-full/8412#8412)
- `Feb 03, 2012` : [Scheduled optimization of tables in MySQL InnoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12201/scheduled-optimization-of-tables-in-mysql-innodb/12205#12205)
- `Mar 25, 2012` : [Why does InnoDB store all databases in one file?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15531/why-does-innodb-store-all-databases-in-one-file/15542#15542)
- `Apr 01, 2012` : [Is innodb_file_per_table advisable?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15906/is-innodb-file-per-table-advisable/15907#15907)

## iblog files (a.k.a. `ib_logfile0`, `ib_logfile1`)

If you want to know what the `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1` are for, they are the InnoDB Redo Logs. *They should never be erased or resized until a full normal shutdown of mysqld has taken place*. If mysqld ever crashes, just start up mysqld. It will read across `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1` to check for any data changes that were not posted to the the double write buffer in `ibdata1`. It will replay (redo) those changes. Once they are replayed and stored, mysqld becomes ready for new DB Connections.

Comment: How the space will be retained in these log files... ? I mean to ask... "for new innodb transactions how the same log files be used if these are filled up completely...."

Comment: My previous comment is about ib_log files....

Comment: @ Uday The space will not be retained on the iblog files until the logbuffer becomes empty. It is a dynamic process, where the log space get occupied and released based on the stalled transaction changes recorded in the log buffer. These log files get occupied completly, when ever you perform some huge data loads, which leads to Innodb errors stating "InnoDB: which exceeds the log group capacity"., which mean Log file size should be bigger to do things. Hope my explanation cleared your doubt.

Comment: `innodb_file_per_table disabled, Data/Index Pages Stored in /var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.ibd` and `innodb_file_per_table enbled, Data/Index Pages Stored in ibdata1` should be vice versa, shouldn't it?

Comment: @rabudde OMG I never noticed that. Thank you. I'll fix it right now !!!

Comment: @rabudde It's fixed now. Thank you again !!!

Comment: Great answer, as always @RolandoMySQLDBA! Your posts really have helped me better understand MySQL config basics and InnoDB stuff in particular.