# Table does not exist even if there is one

Tags: mysql, replication, amazon-ec2

I have MySQL master-slave replication setup in Amazon EC2. For the sake of resilience, I have set up LVM on RAID 10 array, on both master as well as slave. I have been using  [ec2-consistent-snapshot](https://github.com/alestic/ec2-consistent-snapshot)  for some time now to take the snapshot from the slave instance.

So, I tried to create the disks from those snapshots and attach them to a new MySQL installation. Since the new installation would not recognise the LVM and RAID setup, I reactivated the LVM and RAID in the new instance using the following commands.

1. Scan the disks for RAID array members:

   ```
   mdadm --examine --scan <comprising disks>
   ```
2. Reactivate the RAID array:

   ```
   mdadm -A -s
   ```
3. Reactivate the lvm:

   ```
   vgchange -ay
   ```

Since snapshotting took the backup of the `ibdata` and `iblogfiles`, I removed them for the fresh installation. MySQL would start normal.

Help me out of this

Comment: You haven't really asked a question, or explained what errors or problems you're having - only described steps you've taken. Please elaborate on the issue by editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Removed ibdata1? You can* remove iblogfiles but **not** the ibdata1!!
They're system tablespaces storing tables, indexes, metadata, undologs....

*=> Removing iblogs is okay once you stop mysql but **not** while it's running!

**Update:** Removing iblogs is okay *only* after shutting down mysql with *innodb_fast_shutdown disabled*.

You might like to review [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27083/what-exactly-are-iblog-files-in-mysql) to understand what is wrong! You might want to do a restore from the snapshot may be.

Comment: Don't remove iblogs either -- unless you have made a clean shutdown with `innodb_fast_shutdown` turned off.  LVM is equivalent to a power failure.

Comment: Yep... that's why the STAR  is after "can" ;) & was told later on

Comment: * _and_ `innodb_fast_shutdown` turned off.  -- My added qualification.