# AWS RDS Really Odd Error... #1041 OUT OF MEMORY, Buffers OK and Memory OK

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.6, amazon-rds, aws

I have an AWS RDS (MySQL 5.6.35) `db.m3.medium` that has given me a random error when attempting to modify a table's structure in the past two weeks:

`#1041 - Out of memory; check if mysqld or some other process uses all available memory; if not, you may have to use 'ulimit' to allow mysqld to use more memory or you can add more swap space`

I've never encountered this error on even a much smaller instance with much less memory. It should be noted that encryption **is** enabled on this instance, so that might be adding a little bit of load.

When I check the memory statistics in the console, it doesn't appear to be even using anywhere near 100% usage. It doesn't appear that the instance is swapping at all either. After a reboot, I can modify tables fine. This table is very small... < 10 columns, little overhead, and not many rows (<100). Oddly enough, we have not modified the default buffer sizes in RDS (3/4 of instance memory allocation). Not only this, after checking the buffer tables, everything seemed OK as well.

Am I missing something here?

UPDATE: It happened again. Rebooting the RDS server appears to mitigate whatever problem is occurring. Here's a screenshot of buffer statistics at the time of the incident (this is BEFORE the reboot that fixes the problem)...

[image: screenshot]

UPDATE 9/1/2017: I thought that we mitigated the issue for a while after we upgraded our RDS instance to `m4.large`... and for a while, it did. However, while performing some migrations earlier this evening... sure enough, error #1041 - OUT OF MEMORY. I immediately checked our CloudWatch reports for anything out of the ordinary, and our freeable memory is really high, not even concerningly fluctuating. Additionally, a reboot fixed the issue. I have yet to see it happen again, but I'm sure in a few weeks after some transactions it will happen again. **Is this possibly a sign of a corrupted database or something?** We have NEVER had any issues reading or writing to the database, and all applications are using their databases on this server just fine. We just can't initiate `ALTER TABLE` changes from inside phpMyAdmin...

Comment: can you provide the tuning info discussed in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe you are alone here. AWS has push me from 5.7.11 to 5.7.17 and now I am unable to perform Alter table commands when there is any sort of memory pressure on the Database.

Have a look at https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=251866

At this point it looks like there may be an issue present in MySQL 5.6 < 5.6.37 and 5.7 < 5.7.19.

Unfortunately AWS RDS does not have any 5.6 images > 5.6.35 or 5.7 > 5.7.17

Before using 5.7.17 I had used 5.7.11 for some time without issue. If you are able to dump/restore your databases that might be the best option for you, otherwise you can give larger instances a shot.

Comment: I tried a larger instance and no joy - eventually the same thing happened. The statistics inside of the console show NO sign of high memory usage. Could this be a sign of an unhealthy database?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is db.m3.medium, I see two problems, maybe three

## PROBLEM #1 : Available RAM

Since RDS is using 75% of the RAM for [innodb_buffer_pool_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size), this means you only have 960M for the OS. Not a lot of headroom.

## PROBLEM #2 : DB Connections

Multiple DB Connections opening and closing can cause the OS to compete with the DB Connections for available RAM (See my old post : [How costly is opening and closing of a DB connection?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16969/how-costly-is-opening-and-closing-of-a-db-connection/16973#16973))

## PROBLEM #3 : Too many tables in the database

Did you know memory is consumed when you have many tables and columns ?

- `Apr 22, 2014` : [Do Inactive MySQL Databases Consume Memory?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63621/do-inactive-mysql-databases-consume-memory/63650#63650)
- `Apr 21, 2014` : [Adding new tables -- memory usage increases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63591/adding-new-tables-memory-usage-increases/63593#63593)

#### Questions to ask yourself

- Have you added tables recently ?
- Have increased the number of columns in one or more tables ?
- Are there a lot of open file tables to tables after many queries (run `SHOW OPEN TABLES;`) ?

#### SUGGESTION

Perhaps just running `FLUSH TABLES;` will close all open files handles to previously accessed tables just prior to doing any `ALTER TABLE` commands.

## UPDATE 2017-08-15 08:21 EDT

I looked at the buffer statistics at the time of the incident you posted.

- Your InnoDB Buffer Pool is 98.8023% empty (168454 / 170496)
- You only have 31.59375 MB (2022 * [16384](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_page_size) / 1048576) of data
- Here is the part I don't understand

  - You have 23824 pages to be flushed
  - that means you have 372.25 MB (23824 * [16384](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_page_size) / 1048576)
  - That's like 11.78 times more the the actual data

How in the world could 372 MB need to be flushed when there is only 32 MB of data ?

## PROBLEM #4 : Compression (Maybe)

I hope you are not using [innodb_file_format Barracuda](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_format). This requires uncompressing pages in the InnoDB Buffer Pool. Larger Buffer Pool would be needed.  I wrote about this before:

- `Mar 02, 2012` : [innodb_file_format Barracuda](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14246/innodb-file-format-barracuda/14287#14287)
- `Jul 22, 2013` : [MySQL 5.5 High CPU Usage](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46752/mysql-5-5-high-cpu-usage/46799#46799)

## PROBLEM #5: CPU

db.m3.medium only 1 vCPU. That means InnoDB, Encryption, and the OS are all running on 1 vCPU. OUCH !!!

## PROBLEM 1 REVISITED

According to your buffer statistics, you have 2664 MB for the InnoDB Buffer Pool

- The Buffer Pool is supposed to be 75% of the installed RAM
- db.m3.medium only has 3840 MB (3.75 GB). Remaining RAM is 960MB
- Your stats says 75% of RAM is 2664 MB. That means 100% of RAM is 3552 MB.
- Therefore, leftover RAM for the OS is not 960 MB, but 888 MB

## RECOMMENDATION

Please do one or both of the following:

- Stop using Encryption
- Get more RAM (Upgrade Server Class)

Comment: Regarding the 372 MB in the buffer table waiting to be flushed... what would cause that? Is this perhaps an RDS bug that I should be reporting? Perhaps inefficient queries?

Comment: I tried all steps provided, including a major instance type upgrade (to m4.large zone), and am *still* having the same issue. Is this potentially a sign of an unhealthy database?